# Git not recognised as internal or external command in already opened cmd

Tags: git

I have installed GIT. Then in command prompt(which was already open before installation of GIT) I navigated to the folder where GIT was installed. I typed git but showed 'git' is not recognised as an internal or external command. I re-opened cmd and again performed the same operation,this time it worked. My question is why it did not worked for the first time?

Comment: Did you go to the folder where `git.exe` was placed? I ask because on my computer the installation folder has a subfolder `bin` with the executables. As such, if you navigated to the **installation folder** then you probably need to navgiate into the `bin` folder as well.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is this, as far as my knowledge goes when a command prompt window is opened it loads all the path variables and environment variables from the system. If a program modifies the variable after the command prompt is opened, those changes won't be registered in the cmd window until you reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

When git is installed it writes some enviromental variables which are not picked up by the cmd terminal until all cmd terminals are closed.

Comment: I don't think any of those are important if you can execute the `git.exe` file specifically. At least on my computer after I had made a copy of the files for a more "portable" installation, I had no environment variables set and git worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify and expand on the other answers, the `PATH` environment variable defines directories that will be searched when looking for executables (as in when you call `git`). This variable is declared when you open a command prompt, and this instance of `PATH` is not affected by git installation if it is done after the command prompt is opened. So there is no way for the command prompt to know what to execute when you call `git`, thus the error. If you had called it with the path (relative or absolute) to git, it would have executed fine.

Git installation modifies how `PATH` should be defined by adding the path to the git executable: `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`. Only subsequent declarations of `PATH` (such as when you open another command prompt) will reflect these changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you navigated to the *installation folder* in your command prompt then no, it shouldn't have worked.

Since it didn't, then everything seems OK to me.

The problem here is that the executables, such as `git.exe` is placed in a subfolder of the installation folder, named `bin`. Unless you navigate into that folder, `git` as a command won't be found.

As all the other answers here mention, the reason it worked the next time was that the `PATH` variable that was configured by the installation did not take effect for the already open command prompt. As such, the next command prompt window you opened could execute `git` *where* it was, including inside the installation folder.